# Bottle with Gunicorn

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle, gunicorn

What is the difference between running bottle script like this

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'

run(server='gunicorn', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

with command **python app.py** and this

```
from bottle import route, default_app

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'

app = default_app()
```

with command **gunicorn app:app --bind='0.0.0.0:8080'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially nothing.

From the bottle source code for the `GunicornServer` [here](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L2828-#L2843) you can see that a basic application is loaded and run with your argument. From the gunicorn source code [this](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py#L68-L74) is what is invoked by the `gunicorn` command according to setup.py. The only difference is the `WSGIApplication` class is used. Well, `default_proc_name` is either 'app:app' or 'gunicorn' depending on which one you invoked with. None of the other parameters matter in this simple case.