# How do I use python Bottle and Gunicorn with custom settings ini file?

Tags: python, settings, gunicorn, bottle

I'm running a simple [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html) application with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) as a webserver, the application is working fine. My code:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

bottle.run(server='gunicorn', workers="3")
```

**The Problem**

Now I would like to create my own *gunicorn config file* and use it *with bottle*. I want to add a lot of extra functionality to the gunicorn workers (like SSL for example) and using a config file is a great way to do this.

I've tried this:

```
bottle.run(server='gunicorn', config="settings.py.ini")
AND
bottle.run(server='gunicorn', -c="settings.py.ini")
```

I know that in the CLI this the settings file can be set as an extra option like so:

```
-c CONFIG, --config CONFIG
gunicorn --config="settings.py.ini"
```

Anyone knows how to achieve the same thing when using the bottle gunicorn controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by taking a different aproach.

I'm using the code from this question: [Bottle with Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362532/bottle-with-gunicorn)

This makes it possible to use gunicorn from the CLI and load the bottle app in gunicorn. Now I can use the CLI to use gunicorn with config file, it works with bottle. Bottle is now basicly an Gunicorn module.